# Time Series Theorem

Tags: time-series

Consider the following theorem:

> **Theorem.** For any sequence of autocovariances $\{ \lambda_k \}$ generated by a stationary process, there exists a function $F$ such that $$\lambda_k = \int_{(-\pi, \pi]} e^{ik \lambda} dF(\lambda)$$ where $F$ is the unique function on $[-\pi, \pi]$ satisfying
>
> 1. $F(-\pi) = 0$
> 2. $F$ is non-decreasing and right continuous
> 3. For any $0 \leq a \leq b \leq \pi$ we have $F(b)-F(a) = F(-a)-F(-b)$.
>
> Then $F$ is called the spectral distribution function.

So basically, given a set of autocovariances (e.g. $\{E(X_{t}X_{t+1}), E(X_{t}X_{t+2}), \dots, E(X_{t}X_{t+10}) \}$), we can express each of these autocovariances in terms of the spectral distribution function?

**Added.** What is the purpose of the this theorem?

Comment: Isn't that (part of) what the theorem asserts? Perhaps you could be a little more precise about what your difficulty is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a theorem states (and proves) a truth; it does not necessarily have a purpose other than our enlighthening. That said, from the theorem you mention several interesting facts derive. If $dF(\lambda)$ happens to be continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure, then you can restate the theorem as
$$ \lambda_k = \int_{(-\pi,\pi]}e^{ik\lambda} f(\lambda)d\lambda $$
with $f(\lambda)$ being the spectral density function and having an interesting interpretation. It is particularly clear when $k=0$; then you have
$$ \lambda_0 = \sigma^2 = \int_{(-\pi,\pi]} f(\lambda)d\lambda $$
which shows that the total variance of the process can be decomposed in the freuency domain, the contribution of oscillations in one band being given by the integral of $f(\lambda)$ over that band.